# JOIN Multiple Tables with SUM

Tags: sql, join, sum

I need help with the scenario below.

order table

```
orderId    orderAmount
10001      1000.00
10002      2000.00
10003      3000.00
10004      1000.00
10005      1000.00
```

transfer table

```
transferId    orderId    transferAmount
9001          10001      100.00
9002          10001      200.00
9003          10001      25.00
9004          10002      250.00
9005          10002      450.00
9006          10004      100.00
```

returns table

```
returnId      orderId    returnAmount
8001          10001      450.00
8002          10001      50.00
8003          10002      245.00
8004          10003      100.00
```

Result Needed

```
/*include all orders from orders table, even if no transfers or returns*/
orderId       transfers      returns
10001         325.00         500.00 /*sum of transfers and returns per orderId from respective tables*/
10002         700.00         245.00
10003         0.00           100.00
10004         100.00         0.00
10005         0.00           0.00   /*use zero whenever no rows for orderId in respective table*/
```

How can I implement the above in single query?

Comment: Order 1004 or 10004?

Comment: What's the point of the order table? Nothing in your expected output seems to make use of that table. Also, while we can "work out" how you determine your results, why can't you be bothered to explain your calculations? Understanding the ***rules*** to obtain expected output is ***crucial*** to writing the ***correct*** query.

Comment: Sorry for that, it supposed to be 10004
@CraigYoung - what i want is say i have a column which only in Orders table, I need that in the result, for example i just selected only Orderid, 

Basically, i need to list all the orders, with the sum of transfers and returns from the respective tables. If no record in transfers and returns, it need to be shown as 0 like for order 10003, there is no transfer, thus in result, it will be 0.

Comment: @SusobhSugathan Then your data should demonstrate that. I'll make some edits. Also, don't post an image of your data. If you use markdown formatting correctly, it will be very readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  I think the easiest way is `union all`.  If I have the arithmetic correct, you want to add the order amount to transfers but not returns:

```
select orderId,
       sum(transfers) as transfers,
       sum(returns) as returns
from ((select orderId, Amount, 0 as transfers, 0 as returns
       from orders o 
      ) union all
      (select orderId, 0, transferAmount, 0
       from transfers
      ) union all
      (select orderId, 0, 0, returnAmount
       from transfers
      )
     ) otr
group by orderId;
```

Comment: Seems like a strange approach compared to joining aggregated tables. But neatly fills in 0 values for missing rows from certain tables and should perform similarly. _However OP's expected results don't seem to make use of `Order` table and your results would be different. `Result.transfers` is simply sum of `transferAmount`._

Comment: @CraigYoung . . . The OP appears to have changed the question after I answered.

Comment: That aspect of the question wasn't changed. OP only added an image of the "sample data" (which was identical to the data you helped format correctly). I later updated the question based on OP's explanation in comments as to why the `Order` was included in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select all the order lines.
For each order, you subquery the tables linked by the OrderId.

```
SELECT o.orderId
    , (SELECT sum(TransferAmount)
       FROM Transaction t
       WHERE t.OrderId = o.OrderId) 'Transaction'
    , (SELECT sum(r.ReturnAmount)
       FROM Result r
       WHERE r.OrderId = o.OrderId) 'Return'
FROM Order o
```

Comment: Looks good, but i'm concerned about the performance issue using the above query. I fear using subquery might slow down the query performance. Please advice. :)

Comment: I might have huge amount of data in all 3 tables. so does using subquery slowdown the process?

Comment: @SusobhSugathan Sub-queries are not generally a problem. But this is a _correlated sub-query_ (in fact 2 of them). Correlated subqueries repeat the sub-query _per source row_. If the optimiser is unable to plan a more efficient approach, it will be much slower than a solution that doesn't use this technique. Treat it with caution, and look for more efficient approaches such as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42136066/224704

Answer (score 0):

I would use derived tables, something like (Apologies if the syntax is a little off, not tested):

```
SELECT  O.OrderID,COALESCE(T.Total,0) AS [Transfer Total],COALESCE(R.Total,0) AS [Return Total]
FROM    Orders AS O
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT  T.OrderID,SUM(T.TransferAmount) [Total]
        FROM    Transfer_Table AS T
        GROUP BY T.OrderID
        ) AS T ON O.OrderID = T.OrderID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  R.OrderID,SUM(R.ReturnAmount) [Total]
        FROM    Return_Table AS R
        GROUP BY R.OrderId
        ) AS R ON R.OrderId = O.OrderID
```

Comment: Close, but INNER JOIN is going to throw away `Order` rows that don't have a match in `Transfer` or `Returns`. And if you fix that with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you'll be left with `NULL` values where `0` values are expected.

Comment: Leonidas, please note how I edited your answer. SO markup requires 4 spaces left of each line of code. You don't need the html "code" tags. In fact, using them messes up the formatting.

Comment: @CraigYoung very true, an oversight on my part. Left joins indeed.